# How to Transpose & Merge Lines in R

Tags: r, merge, transpose

At the moment, lets say I have a df that looks like this:

```
Number  Value
a1      cat
a1      dog
a2      dog
a3      fish
a3      cat
```

But what I want is for the df to look like this:

```
Number   Cat Fish Dog 
a1        1    0   0
a2        0    0   1
a3        1    1   0
```

How would I go about doing that in R? Any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  No packages are used.

```
tab <- xtabs(~., df)
```

which gives:

```
> tab
      Value
Number cat dog fish
     1   1   1    0
     2   0   1    0
     3   1   0    1
```

To capitalize the columns:

```
colnames(tab) <- sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", colnames(tab), perl = TRUE)
```

Alternately, the names can be capitalized like this:

```
example(chartr) # this will define .simpleCap and capwords functions
colnames(tab) <- capwords(colnames(tab))
```

**Note:** We used this input:

```
Lines <- "Number Value
1      cat
1      dog
2      dog
3      fish
3      cat "
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of pairs, then spread the df (with the dplyr, and tidyr packages):

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Number, Value) %>% summarize(count = n())

spread(df, Value, count, fill = 0)
```

Comment: I bet this is super fast